# delete rows based on value of rows that reference them

Tags: mysql

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
delete c.* from Club c
where c.id in(select club_id from ClubAttrValues where value='E5');
```

but when I try this I get the error

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foroige`.`clubattrvalues`, CONSTRAINT `FKAE90CBE9EE3B7895` FOREIGN KEY (`club_id`) REFERENCES `Club` (`id`))
```

Is there any way to delete everything to do with the every club in `Club` where the value in `ClubAttrValues` is 'E5'. There are multiple rows in `ClubAttrValues` with the same club_id, which would all ideally be deleted, and club_id references id in `Club`.

I have tried setting ON DELETE CASCADE in MySQL workbench but even this seems to make no difference.

The Club table looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address1  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address2  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| county    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fax       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| town      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lft       | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rgt       | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and my ClubAttrValues table:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| club_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Show the table schema.Probably you must remove the foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before deleting try:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

Set it against to 1 when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you set `on delete cascade` for the foreign key column and then

```
delete c
from Club c
inner join ClubAttrValues a on a.club_id = c.id
where a.value = 'E5'
```

### [See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05200/1)